# #1109 - Unknown table 'takes' in field list

Tags: mysql, sql

I am currently trying to test my created trigger so I tried to insert this into my 'takes' table:

```
INSERT INTO takes VALUES ('00001', 'CS-315', '1', 'Spring', 2020, NULL)
```

And this gave me an error:

```
#1109 - Unknown table 'takes' in field list
```

Why? My table definitely exists. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Using insert query, it more accurate if you indicate the columns. Like `INSERT INTO takes (Column1, Column2. Column3, Column4, Column5) VALUES ('00001', 'CS-315', '1', 'Spring', 2020, NULL)`

Comment: `mysql` and `sqlite` are two different DB's. Please only use a tag relative to the DB that you primarily use.

Comment: And `#1109 - Unknown table 'takes' in field list` means that you did not created the table `takes` yet.

Comment: @fonz I have the table takes

Comment: @fonz the current format is completely fine if I want to insert in every column

Comment: @JesseLingLing try to `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS takes` and create again the `takes` table

Comment: @fonz What do you mean by drop table if exists takes?

Comment: I mean `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS yourtable_name` please read more about it hear. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/drop-table.html

Comment: If I drop my current table, how do I create them again? The table is large and I don't think I could recreate one within days

Comment: Make sure you have selected the database where the table 'takes' is.

Comment: @user2260040 Yes I have. I did this both under takes and under the database

Comment: can you run `select * from takes where 1=2`, in the same environment as you attempt this INSERT,  and share the result (column names appearing as empty result set) here?

Comment: Provide complete CREATE TABLE of both tables, complete CREATE TRIGGER statement, the statement which fires the trigger and causes shown error message. *I have the table takes* in what database? and what database is current?

Comment: @fonz None statements which causes implicit commit (including DROP/CREATE TABLE) are allowed in the trigger.

Comment: Check the database in use select database(); check the schema that takes exists in
select table_schema, table_name from information_schema.`TABLES` where upper(table_name) = upper('takes'); check for camel case